# Using knockout.js I need to update my model from a server call then show this on the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am using MVC 4.0 with knockout.js to create a page that will call to a database every 5-10 seconds, and update the model with the new object retrieved from the database, then update the view with the new model.

Currently I am making the initial JSON get call and this is returning the model, and I am then able to bind this to the view. I then set up the getJSON call again to do the update every 10 seconds, and it will execute the function and get back the data, but no update is seen on the screen. I have tried calling the ko.applyBindings after each call, but there is still no update on the page, then it crashes the browser after a few calls.

I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong. I have included the relevant parts of the code below.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var viewModel;

var update = setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON(
                "/Home/Get", {},
                function (model) {
                    viewModel = model;
                    bindViewModel(viewModel);
                });
}, 10000);

$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $.getJSON(
            "/Home/Get", {},
            function (model) {
                viewModel = model;
                bindViewModel(viewModel);
            });
    });


function bindViewModel(viewModel) {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
</script>
```

Table to Display Model

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: Events, as: 'evnts' }">
<span data-bind="text: evnts.LastUpdate"></span>
<table id="EventsTable" style="display:inline; float:left;">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="EvntsHeader" data-bind="visible: evnts.IsVisible">
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: evnts.Name"></span>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="MarketsTable">
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: evnts.Markets, as: 'markets' }">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="MarketHeader">
                                <span data-bind="text: markets.Name"></span>
                                <span data-bind="text: markets.NumberOfRunners"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table id="SelectionTable">
                                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: markets.Selections, as: 'selections' }">
                                        <tr id="Selections">
                                            <td><span data-bind="text: selections.Number, visible: selections.IsVisible"></span></td>
                                            <td><span data-bind="text: selections.Name, visible: selections.IsVisible"></span></td>
                                            <td><span data-bind="text: selections.CurrentPrice, visible: selections.IsVisible"></span></td>
                                            <td><span data-bind="text: selections.OpeningPrice, visible: selections.IsVisible"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controlller - JSON Get

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var model = new TestModel {LastUpdate = DateTime.Now};

        if (TestConstants.Update == false)
        {
            GetModelFirstTime(model);
            TestConstants.Update = true;
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateModel(model, DateTime.Now);
        }

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you want to apply bindings only once, and is usually done on page load. Rather than invoking bindViewModel in your update, try using:

```
ko.mapping.updateFromJS(viewModel, model);
```

If you want to read up a bit more on Mapping - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Let me know if it works or not...

Comment: Tried that and I am still getting the same problem.